# Definite article before 'soul' and zero before 'body' in a Leo Tolstoy quote

Tags: definite-article

In one video the author puts the following quote of Leo Tolstoy.

> Alcohol is a poison, harmful to **the** soul and **_** body, therefore it is a
>   great sin to drink alcohol and to offer it to others. It is an even
>   greater sin to produce and sell this poison.

Actually, I do not have any information about in what language Leo said that, whether it was his native Russian – which does not have any articles in it – or he did it in English.

So, my question is: Why does "the" go before "soul" and not go before "body" for the same reason there?

Comment: They share the same article. This structure is not uncommon.

Comment: @EddieKal so you basically mean the following sentences have completely the same meanings: *Alcohol is a poison, harmful to **the** soul and body*. *Alcohol is a poison, harmful to the soul and **the** body* ?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this topic has been asked about before. You (someone) might be able to find it by searching our site (maybe ["and zero article"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=and+zero+article+is%3Aq)).

Comment: Yes, those sentences have the same meaning. The second article (or possessive) is often omitted when speaking of two related things: "She gave her a knife and fork." "He took off his shoes and socks."

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica yes, it completely does, thanks